# Not able to create a dictionary dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a dictionary dynamically.
i have list of packages and want to create a data as below dynamically

```
package_list = ['package1','package2','package3']

data={
    "packageMap" : {
        "package1" : [],
        "package2" : [],
        "package3" : []
        }
}
```

Below is the code I am trying but failed with error **dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required** :

```
data = {
    "packageMap" : {}
} 

dump = json.dumps(data)
json_data  = json.loads(dump)
for package in package_list:
    json_data["packageMap"].update(f"{package} : []")
```

Comment: Just do `json_data["packageMap"][package] = []`, using `update` makes sense if you already have the dict you want to update with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json_data` is a python dictionary, `update` method exposed by `dict` class requires either a `dict` or any other iterable with key-value pairs instead, you are giving it a string. Replacing that with the key-value pair works fine.

```
data = {
    "packageMap" : {}
} 

dump = json.dumps(data)
json_data  = json.loads(dump)
for package in package_list:
    json_data["packageMap"].update({package: []})
```

Reference:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

Comment: Or simply `json_data["packageMap"][package] = []`, no need to create a dict and call update to use its parts before throwing it away...

Answer (score 0):

As another method, You can add keys to another dictionary and add it to the json later:

```
package_list = ['package1','package2','package3']

packageMap = {}

for package in package_list:
    packageMap[package]=[]

data["packageMap"] = packageMap

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict.update` don't accept str as params. You should check its usage in [build-in type: dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)